# Filtering logcat output

Tags: android, filter, logcat

I know there are plenty of questions like this but I'm sure my case is a little different.

I KNOW how to create filters for different apps but the problem is that my logcat seems to be printing a lot of opengl and other messages like 'JpgDecHal', 'Input', 'Posix' etc.

I want ONLY the Log.d (or .whatever) statements that I put in my code, not all this other stuff.

How do I make sure I only get what I want rather than this? All is well on most other phones.

Here are a few of the lines displayed (that I don't need):

```
12-31 10:56:33.921: D/IPCThreadState(2360): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE     cookie 0xcad6e8
12-31 10:56:54.367: D/My Id(2360): hassan@yopmail.com
12-31 10:56:54.370: I/System.out(2360): [socket][21] connection     /192.168.1.142:80;LocalPort=33289(20000)
12-31 10:56:54.370: I/System.out(2360): [CDS]connect[/192.168.1.142:80] tm:20
12-31 10:56:54.371: D/Posix(2360): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.nettech.Socialcommunity :80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to all the other suggestions; here's a NOT RegEx that will show you everything except the items you list in the ():

```
tag:^((?!InputEventConsistency|memalloc|Resources|global|Facade[B|U]|dalvik|skia|szipinf|APACHE).)*$
```

Of course you need to choose your own terms.  These are just examples of items I've put in the filter.

Comment: The tags (memalloc, resource etc) WON'T be displayed? If so, yours is probably the best answer here.

Comment: Got it to work :) Thanks a lot. I added 'Activity Thread', 'Posix', 'JpgDecHal' and 'OpenGL' to the tags.

Comment: @Asim nice!  Glad it's working for you.  It's certainly made cleaning up the logs easier for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique tag in all your Log statements, and then filter by that tag only. That way, you'll only get the statements with that Tag, even if your app's process has other logged statements like OpenGL etc.

Something like:

```
Log.d("MySuperUniqueTag", "My Message");
```

And then in eclipse filer the LogCat using:

```
tag:MySuperUniqueTag
```

Comment: Yes but.. isn't there any other way? I have several different tags. For example, when the same webservice is called to upload a video, audio and text, the Tags help me differentiate.

Comment: You can filter multiple tags using the OR `|` operator.

Comment: The LogCat filtering box accepts Java RegEx as well, if you need even finer control.

Answer (score 0):

In your filtre put in the classTAG of your app, this will ensure that only logs from your app will appear in the LogCat window.

On the right hand side of the Logcat's search bar there is little box that will (defaultly) have the name `verbose` on it. When you click on the box, change the name to `debug`. This will ensure that only Log.d statements will ocurre in the LogCat window.

I hope this helps.

Comment: All these OPENGL msgs are also debug messages generated by my app. So no that doesn't help :(